# Spacing issue around parenthesis when explorer accessibility is turned on

Tags: mathjax

When the accessibility explorer is activated, there's a spacing issue. The spaces after 'f', 'M', and 'cos' are way too big. It's important that those spaces are small for readability reasons, since (for instance) "M(x)" is a single object, not two separate things as "M (x)" might suggest.

Current behavior
[image]

Expected behavior
[image]

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open https://jsbin.com/ bohitetaka/edit?html,js,output
2. Check how math expression is displayed by making accessibility explorer property to false and true.

When explorer is set to false the spacing is correct, but I also want the accessibility feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the explorer uses semantic-enrichment that modifies the underlying MathML for the expression, and that adds `mrow`s around the parentheses, which in turn causes MathJax to interpret the parentheses as though they came from `\left...\right`, which are spaced differently.

This was fixed in [v3.1.3](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/releases/tag/3.1.3) via [#583](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/issues/583), but the fix has not been back-ported to v2.7.

For now, you can use the following configuration to work around the issue:

```js
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook('MathML Jax Ready', function () {
  var PARSE = MathJax.InputJax.MathML.Parse;
  PARSE.Augment({
    _AddChildren: PARSE.prototype.AddChildren,
    AddChildren: function (mml, node) {394
      this._AddChildren(mml, node);
      if (mml.type === "mrow" && (mml.open || mml.close)) {
        if (mml.open && !mml.data[0].stretchy) delete mml.open;
        if (mml.close && !mml.data[mml.data.length-1].sretchy) delete mml.close;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: great, thanks. How can I use the `v3.1.3` from cdn, similar to the way I use `2.7.7` currently, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#using-mathjax-from-a-content-delivery-network-cdn) for details.  Note that v3 was a major update and the API has changed, including the configuration object.  See [Upgrading from v2](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html) for details, and note that there is a [configuration conversion tool](https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/convert-configuration/convert-configuration.html) to help convert v2 to v3 configurations.